# Is there a simple way to repeat the last bot response after scorable or controller detour

Tags: botframework

During a bot conversation, if the user response is "detoured", is there a simple way to repeat the last bot response (typically a question). I'd like to not have to store off the last bot response in a data store.

example:

Bot: What is your name?

User: John

Bot: Hi John. How old are you?

User: help

Bot: To use this bot, just answer the simple questions and don't over think it.

Bot: Hi John. How old are you?

User: 25

I'm not sure if this is possible with a scorable, or my preference, in the messagesController Post method using the dialog stack as in:

```
if (activity.Text != null && (activity.Text.ToLower() == "help"))
{
    var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
    {
        var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
        // DO something here?
    }
}
```